# What do people mean when they say they don't believe in the rules of math?

Tags: arithmetic, education, math-history

For example, I recently received a message on Reddit from someone who specifically stated he doesn't believe in the order of operations, and that it is some conspiracy and that I shouldn't teach it at all. I don't understand what belief has to do with it? Isn't arithmetic objective? Isn't all applied mathematics objective? Can someone just dismiss a fundamental rule of math? I am so confused now. How on earth would anything ever work if there were no rules to remove ambiguity from mathematical expressions? Help? (Yes - I looked at MANY posts about order of operations. I haven't seen anybody or any question/answer address this notion of "believing" in math as though it were a matter of opinion.) Confused and frustrated. Please help.

Comment: It's either a troll or a minority belief, just saying.

Comment: Well math is completely made up by humans, thus you can't really belive in order of operations, though you can choose to use a different order of operation, but more importantly I don't think you should pay attention to random people on Internet.

Comment: The order of operations is a notation rule, rather than a "truth" rule. So, for example, the fact that we read $1+2\cdot 3$ as $1+(2\cdot 3)$ is merely a convention, like a language. There have been programming languages, such as APL, that do not obey this convention, and then $1+2\cdot 3 = (1+2)\cdot 3$.

Comment: You don't say anything, mathematics is not about truth or belief. Mathematics relates to real world only through models, which can be more or less accurate (which doesn't have anything to do with mathematics itself). Nothing in mathematics actually exists, it's entirely made up.

Comment: That said, it would be entirely different if the person said, "I don't believe that addition is commutative on the integers." That's an actual mathematical  rule, not a notation rule.

Comment: But, as Pie says, you are letting yourself be emotionally affected by a reddit troll. That's a more important thing to learn. :)

Comment: The only thing in mathematics that needs some belief is consistency of foundations, which we can't prove ([hopefully](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel's_incompleteness_theorems)) within itself.

Comment: The order of operations is a grammar of notation rather than something that comes from the axioms of arithmetic.  There are multiple mathematical notations (e.g. polish notation).
The order of operation becomes a problem when someone goes out of there way to construct an expression that is likely to misinterpreted.  e.g. $3+6\div 2+1$.  Rather than beating over the head that there is one way to read this, we should be teaching how to write these expressions clearly and unambiguously.
However, sometimes we are confronted with a poorly written expression and we need agreed upon rules.

Comment: People say all kinds of crazy things, don't let it shake you up.

Comment: If someone tells you that they don't believe in the order of operations, smile politely and look for better company.

Comment: Now, I have heard a respectable mathematician say that he did not believe in the existence of the real numbers.

Comment: You should remember that this reasoning applies to all human communication, not just mathematical communication. By this reasoning, English, Spanish, Arabic, Polish and all other natural languages are conspiracies about how we should interpret the noises our fellow human beings make. As Roger Scruton wrote somewhere, your antagonist in a debate like this is telling you not to agree with him, so don't.

Comment: I sometimes fail to believe in the real numbers. Also, discontinuous functions. @DougM

Comment: This does seem to be a classical troll-bait scheme in some dark corners of the internet.

Answer (score 6):

Order of operations is more a question about notation and communication.

In formal mathematics, you might require parentheses everywhere, so that you never write $1+2\cdot 3,$ or even $1+2+3,$ but rather $1+(2\cdot 3)$ and $(1+2)+3$.

The reason we decide to *add* order of operations to our informal notation is to make our mathematics cleaner and easier to read. You end up with a lot of parentheses if you don't have an unambiguous order of operations. We pick a standard order of operations, rather than everybody picking their own order, because the goal is clearer communication.

In particular, since order of operations is merely a question of language, it's a bit like a person saying, "I don't believe in English," or "I don't believe in Arabic numerals." Order of operations is a standard to make communication easier and cleaner.

We've picked an order of operations. It is neither true nor false, it is just either "this is how we are talking," or "this is not how we are talking."

There have been programming languages, such as APL, that use the left-to-right order of operations. So then $1+2\cdot 3=(1+2)\cdot 3$.

And then there are languages where we don't use "infix" notation at all - where we write $+(1,\cdot(2,3))$ for $1+(2\cdot 3)$.

Answer (score 2):

The order of operations, and other things, are not provable, but they are set and agreed upon conventions made by mathematicians. These such conventions avoid confusion in certain situations.

Let's say you have the expression $3\cdot3+4$. If the order of operations didn't exist, Person A could evaluate the expression as $3\cdot3+4=9+4=13$, while Person B could essentially write $3\cdot3+4=3\cdot7=21$. Obviously, $13\neq 21$, so one expression can't have two values. So mathematicians decided on the order in which multiple operations are carried out (the familiar PEMDAS).

If someone wanted to rebel against a rule of math, **they could**, but everyone else would be following the rules, and he/she will be the only person who wants to dismiss a rule. So math rules are subjective, because mathematicians decided on them. So too bad for the guy who sent the message.

However, note that some rules are just obvious that they exist (like the Commutative Property of Multiplication). These rules are rigid, and could not be broken in the real number system. (See comment below)

(If they had organized the order of operations differently, we would be doing things a different way! Imagine doing addition before exponentation!)

Comment: Well, it is important to distinguish this kind of rule from "math rules" like commutativity, which aren't subjective, they are either true of false. The real problem with rejecting order of operations is that you will miscommunicate your meaning to other people, and visa versa, you will misread the meaning of other people.

Comment: Hi all! Thank you so much for your insights. I came up with this explanation for someone who was trolling...

Answer (score 2):

A conspiracy "theorist" is essentially paranoid and delusional and cannot be reasoned with. Anything you say is dismissed as propaganda from the world-wide conspiracy against him, while he feels his importance in having discovered a great truth. He has the advantage, and the security, of never being wrong about anything. But he also has a constant resentment about the lack of acknowledgement, from others, of his importance.

Recommended: A Budget Of Trisectors by Underwood Dudley..... I would call this book the tale of a mathematician's close encounters with cranks of the mathematical kind.